# When are Bombers better than Sprayers?

Tags: creeper-world-3-arc-eternal

In Creeper World, there's a marvelous substance called Anti-Creeper that is *exactly* the same as the Creeper that's trying to kill you, with two key differences that make it great for holding territory:

1. It doesn't try to kill you
2. It mutually annihilates any Creeper it touches

There are two delivery methods for this miracle material: Bombers and Sprayers. Sprayers are (occasionally mobile) ground-based turrets that shoot a steady stream of Anti-Creeper, while Bombers are, well, bombers: they pick up Anti-Creeper at a landing pad, then drop it wherever you want it. There's another flying unit, the Strafer, that simply shoots Creeper and destroys it.

The problem I have with Bombers is that I can't think of any purpose for them that isn't better served by Sprayers or Strafers. If you're trying to set up a base somewhere inside a pile of creeper, then the Strafers are (in my experience so far) faster and better at destroying Creeper, while landing a Sprayer (possibly backed by a Guppy or two carrying Anti-Creeper reloads) gives a much more steady supply of Anti-Creeper than the slow-moving bombers, once you've Strafed the Creeper down to reasonable levels. (For reference on my skill level, I've completed the main campaign and a few dozen additional levels, of which about a half-dozen were in the hard-mode Tortured Space worlds.)

I have occasionally built squads of bombers to drop unholy amounts of Anti-Creeper somewhere, and they can create a wonderfully large puddle of Anti-Creeper, but by the time I can manage to do that, I am filthy stinking rich and am simply cleaning up the last of the Creeper. At that point, I can build lots of *anything*, and swiftly overwhelm whatever Creeper is left.

In what situations are Bombers better than any of the alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use Strafers to attack the creeper at its source. I use Bombers to create a beachhead area to make it safe for landing guppies and building out from the beach head. I split the load between ammo for the Strafers and Anti-Creeper for the bombers. On some maps I've played, this has been important. In others, not so much.

While a beachhead area can be created with just Strafers, I find that with the way I prefer to play and build, doing what I described above is safer for the early construction process, as anti-creeper hangs around for a long time, covering the "reload and return to attacking" cycle. I've had large swarms of strafers "sync up" in their reload cycle when I did not include the bombers. That led to frustration as my beachhead was overwhelmed before the strafers got back on station. Using bombers, I have this issue much less often.